# How to convert / explode dict column from pyspark DF to rows

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I have json file with the following structure:

```
{
    "name": {
        "0": "name1",
        "1": "name2",
        "2": "name3"
    },
    "id": {
        "0": "00001",
        "1": "00002",
        "2": "00013"
    }
}
```

When I read this json file to spark DF (with python)
I receive DF with dictionaries at each column:

```
schema  = StructType([
      StructField("name",StringType(),True),
      StructField("id",StringType(),True)
  ])
spark_df = spark.read.schema(schema).json('path_to_json_file', multiLine=True)
spark_df.show()
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|      name                           |           id                        |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|{"0":"name1","1":"name2","2":"name3"}|{"0":"00001","1":"00002","2":"00013"}|
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

How do I explode each column to have only the values:

```
+------+-----+
| name | id  |
+------+-----+
|name1 |00001|
+------+-----+
|name2 |00002|
+------+-----+
|name3 |00013|
+------+-----+
```

I tried to use `explode` function but receive an error:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
spark_df.select('*', f.explode('id').alias('id')).show()

raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'explode(`id`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string;;\n'Project [name#860, id#861, explode(id#860) AS id#947]\n+- Relation[name#860,id#861] json\n"
```

I also tried `from_json` function but for that I have to define an inner schema, and this is something I cannot do as number of values is unknown. I tried this schema but received only nulls.

```
schema = StructType([StructField('key1', StringType(), True)])
```

Basically what I do know is only the upper keys names (that should become fields names), but number of records that I will get is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your input schema is wrong. Change it with a `MapType`:

```py
schm= T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("name", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType()), True),
        T.StructField("id", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType()), True),
    ]
)
df = spark.read.schema(schm).json("path_to_json_file", multiLine=True)

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- json: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |-- id: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Then, assuming both `name` and `id` have the same number of inputs:

```py
df.withColumn("key", F.explode(F.map_keys("json.name"))).select(
    F.col("json.name").getItem(F.col("key")).alias("name"),
    F.col("json.id").getItem(F.col("key")).alias("id"),
).show()

+-----+-----+
| name|   id|
+-----+-----+
|name1|00001|
|name2|00002|
|name3|00013|
+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Steven and @Alex Ott!
This is what worked for me based on your suggestions:

```py
schema = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("name", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType()), True),
        T.StructField("id", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType()), True),
    ]
)
spark_df = spark.read.schema(schema).json("path_to_json_file", multiLine=True)

spark_df.withColumn(
    "name", F.explode(F.map_values("name"))
).withColumn(
    "id", F.explode(F.map_values("id"))
).select("name", "id").show()

+-----+-----+
| name|   id|
+-----+-----+
|name1|00001|
|name2|00002|
|name3|00013|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Please do not accept your own answer. You are doing a cartesian product. I do not see how you got this result with your current code. You should have 9 lines.